# Avoiding repeating labels with the same value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, duplication

I would like to know if is possible, maybe with some of the code, to avoid repeating labels of different elements of my layer if these have the same value.

I have attached this example:

[image]

These are two elements with the same value in the `"nam"` column. There are other examples which have 20 elements with the same value for example.

Comment: doea https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445590/show-single-label-for-features-grouped-by-identical-attributes-in-qgis help?

Comment: This looks like a roads layer. If so, when I had the same problem I dissolved the various pieces of the road together into a single feature which then gave me much better control over label placement.  After all, these pieces are all part of a single logical road; the breakdown into multiple features is just an artifact of digitization or some other issue about representation that is unrelated to how I wanted to show it on my map.

Comment: Hi @Llaves!. Yes, I had that idea and, for example, dissolve and then split the feature into a few elements to have more than one label. I thought some code could automate this situation. I'll try the option that @IanTurton gave.

Comment: I presume you have tried the in built 'Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels' option first?

Comment: Yes @she_weeds, exactly. But it doesn't seem to work at all well.

Comment: You don't have to split the dissolved lines to get multiple labels. Go to Properties->Labels->Placement and look for the repeating labels checkbox