# Point shapefile has duplicate labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, labeling, sql

I have a point shapefile with a attribute table which has many rows. In the 'Location_Names' column there are occasional duplicates since some people live in the same location. Consequently, there are duplicate entries within the x and y coordinates, which are also present in columns.
I then wanted to label each point with the location name but I see some location names twice. I only want each lable once. I think there is some sort of SQL expression "Group by:= "Location_Name". But Im still not that familiar with SQL so I cannot find the correct and full expression. I work with QGIS. I dont want to change anything in the attribute table itself.

Comment: Have a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445590/show-single-label-for-features-grouped-by-identical-attributes-in-qgis/445671#445671 and all the Linked and Related questions on the sidebar to the right and see if they help?

Answer (score 0):

Use Label Placement Mode `Offset from point`. Like this, you see only one label.

*Point layer, styled as point cluster to show where several points overlap. Only one label is visible per point cluster as you can see: the point in the upper middle represents 7 overlapping points and is selected - from the 7 selected features in the attribute table (blue), only one label is visible:*
[image]

Comment: I dont want the coordinates. I want the Name of the locations which are in the attirbute table. They are duplicated. The expample in the link which is posted by she_weeds above visualize my situation really well.

Comment: This also works with the name - see updated answer.