# QGIS - How to show only one value when having multiple same values by expression

Tags: qgis, expression, select

I wonder how could I show by expression only one labels when having the same values multiple times?
Does an "unique" function exists in QGIS?

[image]

For my column "abrev_county" I would like to show one time: SIC, one time: RAD and one time: TUN

Comment: I am not sure it would work in my case as I don't want to aggregate() features. But thanks @MrXsquared

Comment: I found an answer, hope it will help : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445590/show-single-label-for-features-grouped-by-identical-attributes-in-qgis

Comment: Yes it does @Vincé